# generate a new dataset based on individual information

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:10, baseline = c(1.8,2.4,3.2,2.3,2.1,2.2,3,2.8,2,2.9))
```

I want to create a new column called "response", this column should be created based on the following equation:

individual response=individual baseline+0.5*sin(2*3.14*(t-7.5)/24)

in this equation, t is generated based on this vector

```
t=rep(seq(0,24,by=0.1))
```

so for each ID, there should be 241 responses generated. How could I generate the new dataset containing ID, baseline, time, and response?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
library(reshape2)
res <- melt(apply(df[,2, drop=FALSE], 1, 
           function(x) x+0.5*sin(2*3.14*(t-7.5)/24)))

indx <- rep(1:nrow(df), each=241)


df1 <- cbind(df[indx,], time= rep(t, nrow(df)), response=res[,3])
row.names(df1) <- NULL
dim(df1)
#[1] 2410    4

head(df1,3)
#  ID baseline time response
#1  1      1.8  0.0 1.337870
#2  1      1.8  0.1 1.333034
#3  1      1.8  0.2 1.328518
```

Or

```
t <- seq(0,24, by=0.1)
indx <- rep(1:nrow(df), each=length(t))
df2 <- within(df[indx,], {response<-baseline+0.5*sin(2*3.14*(t-7.5)/24)
                          time <- t})

row.names(df2) <- NULL
all.equal(df1, df2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: what does `1` mean in the `apply` function? Does it mean the function apply to the rows?

Comment: @dzadi `1` is the `MARGIN` for `apply`.  Here, I am just using `melt` on the output generated by `apply`

Comment: @dzadi To clarify akrun's comment: yes, the function is applied to each row.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
t <- rep(seq(0, 24, by = 0.1), each = nrow(df))
vals <- 0.5 * sin(2 * 3.14 * (t - 7.5) / 24)
new_df <- cbind(df, t, response = df$baseline + vals)
```